# 3x3 Matrix Rotation with non uniform scaling

Tags: c++, math, opengl, matrix, rotational-matrices

I am having some trouble dealing with matrix transforms. For the test I have a chain of 10 squares, each parented to the previous square. I can then apply a rotation to each square and get this result...

[image: No scaling applied]

This is correct, exactly what I want. Now here is the same thing with the 8th square scaled uniformly.

[image: Uniform scaling applied]

Again, this is perfect. The children are inheriting their parents transforms. Now the problem comes when I apply a non-uniform scale to the 8th square.

[image]

This picture is a subtle example, but I hope you guys get the idea. The last square is not touching the previous squares corner. It also may not be apparent but the last two squares are actually not the correct dimensions. This becomes more apparent if I apply more rotation.

Here is the code where I construct the matrix.

```
maths::mat3 DisplayObject::getGlobalTransform() {

    maths::mat3 output(1.0f);
    output *= maths::mat3::Rotate(rotation);
    output *= maths::mat3::Scale(scale);
    output *= maths::mat3::Translate(position);

    if(parent != nullptr){
        output *= parent->getGlobalTransform();
    }

    return output;

}
```

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is how I am applying rotations and scales.

```
mat3 mat3::Rotate(float angle)
{
    mat3 result(1.0f);

    float r = toRadians(angle);
    result.elements[0] = cos(r);
    result.elements[1] = -sin(r);
    result.elements[3] = sin(r);
    result.elements[4] = cos(r);

    return result;
}

mat3 mat3::Scale(const vec2& scale)
{
    mat3 result(1.0f);
    result.elements[0] = scale.x;
    result.elements[4] = scale.y;
    return result;
}
```

... and here is how I am getting them out again...

```
float mat3::GetRotation() const
{
    return atan2(elements[1], elements[0]);
}

vec2 mat3::GetScale() const
{   
    return vec2(rows[0].Magnitude(), rows[1].Magnitude());
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Not quite, I just tried to make sure. Thanks though.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Then I get a similar, but equally wrong result haha. However, it doesn't mess up the uniform scaling version, which is a shame, because now I don't know which order is right!

Comment: What's your target result ? only one *rectangle* or many *rectangles* ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for that, strange that it works the same both ways. But you are right, I've updated that line. (I'll edit the post to match). The non-uniform scale problem remains though.

Comment: @Orace The target result, all of the squares should have their corners touching, and inheriting their parents scales. Works with uniform scaling.

Comment: @PeterGilmour can you show us how you compute rotation and translation ?

Comment: @Orace Sure, I think it could be an issue with how I'm pulling the scale or rotation out of the matrix at the end. I'll add that code to the end of the question.

Comment: @PeterGilmour sorry but your edit is not useful here, my question was how did you get/compute the `rotate` and `position` values ?

Comment: @Orace Sorry about that, they are simply member vars, a float for rotation, a vec2 for position and a vec2 for scale. Then that method "getGlobalTransform" returns a mat3 for each "displayObject". That's used by the renderer which creates the render batches. Does that help?

Comment: What is your expectation?  Are you expecting all the rectangles to touch each other at their corner vertex?  If so, you should say so explicitly in your question.  You just said non-specific things like "the problem comes from..." and "I hope you guys get the idea".  And provided a picture of some shapes.  It would greatly help if you describe your expected results and actual results rather than relying on us to guess what you think is wrong with your pictures and what "the problem" is.

Comment: @PeterGilmour getting there ;)  Now you need to explain what you tried.  Please disclose how you are computing the combination of rotation, scale and position that you are expecting will produce a transformation that puts the corner of a child coincident with the opposite corner of its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this:

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265
#define M 50.0f

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        glTranslatef(1, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(25.0f, 0, 0, 1);
        glScalef(1.2, 1, 0);

        glColor3f(1.0f-i/M, i/M, 0.0f);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(1.0, 0.0);
        glEnd();
    }

    glFlush();
}

void myinit() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 250.0, 0.0, 250.0);
    glTranslatef(125, 125, 0);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(501, 501);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("59531834");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    myinit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

And it give the expected result:

[image: Spiral of touching rectangles]

The correct matrix order seams to be PTRS : Parent, Translate, Rotate, Scale.

*Edit*: PTSR works to.

So try this:

```
maths::mat3 DisplayObject::getGlobalTransform() {

    maths::mat3 output(1.0f);

    if(parent != nullptr){
        output *= parent->getGlobalTransform();
    }

    output *= maths::mat3::Translate(position);
    output *= maths::mat3::Scale(scale);
    output *= maths::mat3::Rotate(rotation);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for running that for me. This confirms that it's an issue with my matrix maths code and not above that.

Comment: In your example, it would make more sense to just copy `parent->getGlobalTransform()`'s result to `output` rather than going through a relatively-expensive matrix multiplication.